# How do you get a Bootstrap Dropdown Menu to work with AngularJS ng-repeat using a controller?

Tags: c#, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to both Bootstrap and AngularJS. I've been researching this problem for a while now, and I can't find what's wrong. The dropdown appears, and you can click on it, but nothing happens when you click on the arrow for the drop down. 
Here's the code I've been working with:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="dropdown" style="position: absolute; left: 60px; top:       115px;">
            <button class=" btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" type="button"     data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenu1"
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                Select an Office
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li ng-repeat="office in ctrl.offices"><a ng-   click="moveMap(office.latitude, office.longitude)">{{office.name}}</a></li>
            </ul>
```

I found an example like this at this site: http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/06/29/how-to-work-with-the-bootstrap-dropdown-in-angularjs.aspx

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P3HeHgiMi0qKe0aH6Z0X) with your code, everything seems to be setup right. I'd double check to make sure you're including jquery and bootstrap's javascripts. Other than that, I'd actually suggest using [Angular UI's bootstrap directives](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown). It makes things a whole lot easier.

Stack Overflow made me post code because I have a plunker link... it's weird.

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="dropdown" style="position: absolute; left: 60px; top:       115px;">
        <button class=" btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" type="button"     data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenu1"
                  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
              Select an Office
          <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li ng-repeat="office in offices"><a ng-click="moveMap(office.latitude, office.longitude)">{{office.name}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works and I'm now getting the information from my controller. I still have a problem with the fact that the options won't go into the menu. They're showing up as a list underneath them. Here's a link to what I see. localhost:62224/App/index.html#/itmap The point of it is that you are supposed to be able to click one of the options form the dropdown and it take you to that location(office) on the map. @SgtPepper43

Comment: That's a link to localhost, I can't see that. If the offices are just showing up as a list, then it sounds like something's wrong with the css.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use ng-model instead of ng-repeat if that is an acceptable solution for you. Something like this:

```
<select class="dropdown fullWidth" ng-model="ctrl.offices"> 
     <option value="offices.Name"></option>
</select>
```